# Reading selectable portions of a line from an existing file

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am making a language in Python for my Computer Science class, and I need to know how to read certain parts of a line in a file. For instance, if there is a "for" in the first part, then read whats in the "()", then check for a "{", then go to the next line. 
I tried using "if x in line:", but this doesn't make sure it's in the right order. I also can not figure out how to get only a small portion of the line, such as the first three letters, or the next three letters after the first three. I am trying to make this without having to the characters as single variables, or as a list. I prefer to have the small portion saved as a string, to implement this part into another script after it reads the line.

Comment: You mean making a language 'parser'?  Use string split to make a list of strings of the individual tokens. That's different from a list of letters.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement this now, I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular Expressions can check the syntax of a line for you before you split it. For example, with a javascript/ C style for loop:

```
for(x=1;x<=10;x++){ //Note, some coders drop this { to the next line.
    do_something();
}
```

The Python RE will be something like:

```
import re
if re.match("for([\w|\S]+)[{|\S]", line.strip()):
    from_first_bracket = line.split("(")[1]
    for_loop_conditions = from_first_bracket.split(";")
    # last item in for_loop_conditions list has extra punctuation:
    for_loop_conditions[2] = for_loop_conditions[2].split(")")[0]
```

Now in the variable for_loop_conditions is stored: ['x=1','x<=10','x++']
The line is striped to get rid of any proceeding whitespace the coder may have put in front of their for loop to denote nesting. I haven't accounted for white space between the 'for' and the '(' or striping white space from the final list, but I have accounted for writing the { on the next line and incrementing by x = x + 2.